# What is the proper way to register view with viewmodels in Prism.DryIoc

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism, dryioc

I'm using the Prism Template Pack for Visual Studio for Mac to generate a new project (tried both shared and pcl) then updating to 7.0.0.340-ci. Is registration of the views to view models done by convention?

When I try to run this app it throws this exception: `Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInternalInconsistencyException Reason: Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch.`

Here is the code for the main app.

```
    public partial class App : PrismApplication
    {
        public App(IPlatformInitializer initializer = null) : base(initializer) { }

        protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            NavigationService.NavigateAsync("MainPage?title=Hello%20from%20Xamarin.Forms");
        }

        protected override void RegisterTypes(Prism.Ioc.IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
        {
            Prism.Mvvm.ViewModelLocationProvider.Register<MainPage,MainPageViewModel>();
        }

        //protected override void RegisterTypes()
        //{
        //    Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<MainPage>();
        //}
    }
```

I had to comment out the bottom lines and redo the override due to incompatible signatures.

Where did the Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation go or what is it's replacement?

I also tried it without any code in the RegisterTypes method.

In a debug session exploring the NavigationService properties says MainPage is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RegisterTypes method should look like this.
In prism forms 7.x pages used for navigation must be registered via RegisterForNavigation<>() or RegisterForNavigation().

```
    protected override void RegisterTypes(Prism.Ioc.IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<MainPage,MainPageViewModel>();
    }
```